# Does the idea of private ip address in ipv6?

Tags: networking, ip, ipv6, subnet

For the idea of private, I mean it like 10.*.*.* idea of ipv4. It seems ipv6 don't conserve ip addresses like these any more.

So, what if I want to create a private subnet which I don't want the others to know my subnet number or access my subnet with ip address. I can create my own range of ip subnet number, but it seems in that way, it would conflicts with global ip address.

I know the idea of link local address, but I think that's useless when I want several links to constitute a network.

Comment: See [Unique Local Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address).

Comment: Why not use IPv4 for private addresses? Hardware will support both IPv4 and IPv6 and IPv6 will most likely be used for public use, whereas IPv4 can still be used locally.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just setting up a private local network for development/testing and don't have any actual IPv6 connectivity of your own (or your ISP is stupid and only gave you a /64) then [unique local addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address) will work fine for you.

However, unique local addresses cannot be used for connectivity to the global Internet. If you need this, you should get global addresses and a proper firewall (as [NAT is not needed and strongly discouraged in IPv6](https://serverfault.com/q/184524/126632)).

To get a /48 ULA prefix, visit [this generator](http://www.kame.net/%7Esuz/gen-ula.html) and throw in a MAC address. (Using a MAC address to generate the prefix is specified by [RFC 4193](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193), which defines unique local addresses.)